# Facet pivot on interval.facet field in addition to another field

Tags: solr, lucene, intervals, facet

I have this query (date is stored as ISO string):

`q=*:*&facet.mincount=1&rows=0&facet.interval=date&f.date.facet.interval.set=[2017-01-01,2017-12-31]&f.date.facet.interval.set=[2018-01-01,2018-12-31]&facet.pivot=category&rows=0&facet.limit=1000`

I would like to "double pivot" the facet.interval as well as another field `category`.  I have tried using local parameter reference to no avail, e.g.:

`q=*:*&facet.mincount=1&rows=0&facet.interval={!tag=d}date&f.date.facet.interval.set=[2017-01-01,2017-12-31]&f.date.facet.interval.set=[2018-01-01,2018-12-31]&facet.pivot={!tag=d}category&rows=0&facet.limit=1000`

That returns the same data.

How can I connect these two "groupings" to get pivots of pivots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `facet.query` and `facet.pivot` as described by this documentation: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/faceting.html#Faceting-Thefacet.interval.setparameter